# How to show Action Keys in window application always

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a window application that has a menu that contains some items like 'File', 'Open','Save','Close'. I have added a Action Keys to the every items in menu as given below.

```
&File, &Open, &Save, &Close
```

Now when I run my application the all items visible without underline (Ex. File, Open , Save, Close) and when I press Alt button it appears with underline. And when I press Alt again the underline go invisible.

My problem is how can I set Action Keys to all the menu items that the underline always be visible either I press Alt button or not and when page load first time.

I am using Visual Studio 4.0 and Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks.It is working but how to enable "Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys" using C#.because it is for full Operating System not for only any application.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions is overriding of menu items painting.
For example when using the MenuStrip you can override it painting using the following code:

```
menuStrip1.Renderer = new CustomMenuStripRenderer();
//
class CustomMenuStripRenderer : ToolStripSystemRenderer {
    protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e) {
        e.TextFormat &= ~TextFormatFlags.HidePrefix; // Clear the "HidePrefix" bit
        base.OnRenderItemText(e);
    }
}
```